# Casting IEnumerable<Derived> to IEnumerable<BaseClass>

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, casting, .net-2.0

I have a class which I use to enumerate through lists from my database. All tables in the database have their own class with their own properties, and they all derive from DatabaseTableRow.

```
public class DatabaseLinkRowsEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>, IEnumerable<T> where T : DatabaseTableRow
```

I have a User class, which derives from Page, which derives from DatabaseTableRow. I then have a property that returns a DatabaseLinkRowsEnumerator, a list of users.

I also have a UI function that displays lists of any Page in a horizontal list, with the image, name and a link.

```
protected string GetVerticalListModuleHtml(IEnumerable<Page> pages)
```

Now all I want to do is pass the value I have of DatabaseLinkRowsEnumerator to this function. User derives from Page, and DatabaseLinkRowsEnumerator is an IEnumerator. Even when I try to cast, I get the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Database.DatabaseLinkRowsEnumerator`1[Database.User]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Database.Page]'.
```

I'm using ASP.NET 2.0. Does anyone have any ideas of how to cast/convert this without making an entire copy of each?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using .NET 2.0, it's *slightly* awkward, but not too hard:

```
public static IEnumerable<TBase> Cast<TDerived, TBase>
    (IEnumerable<TDerived> source)
    where TDerived : TBase
{
    foreach (TDerived item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
IEnumerable<Page> pages = UtilityClass.Cast<User, Page>(users);
```

This will evaluate it lazily. In LINQ it's easier - you use the `Cast` extension method:

```
var baseSequence = derivedSequence.Cast<BaseClass>();
```

In .NET 4, `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in `T` so there's a reference type conversion from `IEnumerable<DerivedClass>` to `IEnumerable<BaseClass>` already :)

Comment: This is true if the inheritance is set up properly but in the OP's post I'm not seeing a relationship between DatabaseTableRow and Page.

Comment: @Justin, the OP said that Page derives from DatabaseTableRow

Comment: I'm getting slightly confused here though.. Where would you put this method?

Comment: @Connell: Anyway - in a utility class for example. Just call it from wherever you need the sequence.

Comment: @Connell: I'd forgotten to include the type parameters in the method, which probably didn't help. I've updated the method and given an example.

Comment: Ah right, I was trying to be clever and putting it in the DatabaseLinkRowsEnumerator class. Which wouldn't work because that wouldn't necessarily be. And yeah I worked out the type bit, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do that:

```
DatabaseLinkRowsEnumerator<User> users = ...
IEnumerable<Page> = users.Cast<Page>();
```

EDIT: the `Cast` extension method is not available in .NET 2.0. You can use Jon Skeet's implementation as a normal static method instead. If you're using VS2008, you can also use [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx), which allows you to use Linq to Objects when targeting .NET 2.0

Comment: Isn't Enumerable.Cast<>() a LINQ method, introduced in .NET 3.5?